# vue error "cannot read property of undefined (reading 'call')" after building project

Tags: vue.js, development-environment, production-environment

```js
import Root from './Root.vue';
import NotFound from '../views/NotFound.vue';

const locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');

const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirect: locale,
  },
  {
    path: '/:locale/',
    component: Root,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'company/:company_id',
        name: 'Company',
        component: () => import('../views/dashboard/Dashboard.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: () => import('@/views/dashboard/Dashboard.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'notification',
        name: 'Notification',
        component: () => import('@/views/dashboard/Notification.vue'),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound,
  },
];

export default routes;
```

I have an application and there is two mode for building it and here is my **vue.config.js** file

```js
const path = require('path');

let publicPath;
let outputDir;
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'development':
    publicPath = '/';
    outputDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/development/');
  break;
  case 'production':
    publicPath = '/';
    outputDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/production/');
  break;
  default:
    publicPath = '/';
    outputDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/development/');
}

module.exports = {
  publicPath,
  outputDir,
};
```

but sometimes in the development mode or in the production mode after page builds I get this error and the current component will not mount

[image]

The problem is when the code runs in the production or development mode the above error occurs and the current component don't render.

Comment: The error is coming from your router file, and not being able to render a function/template from that. What does your router file look like?

Comment: @Houshman85Thanks for your respond. I added my routes.js file at the top of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by not defining my routes in lazy loading and instead of importing them I use them as require and that solve the problem completely :)

and this solved the issue

```js
const Root = require('./Root.vue');
const NotFound = require('@/views/NotFound.vue');
const Notification = require('@/views/dashboard/Notification.vue');
const Dashboard = require('@/views/dashboard/Dashboard.vue');

const locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');

const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirect: locale,
  },
  {
    path: '/:locale/',
    component: Root.default,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'company/:company_id',
        name: 'Company',
        component: Dashboard.default,
      },
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: Dashboard.default,
      },
      {
        path: 'notification',
        name: 'Notification',
        component: Notification.default,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound.default,
  },
];

export default routes;
```